# Understanding of the term $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

I believe i have some difficulty understanding the actual meaning of $Ax=b$

Following are two questions, which i would appreciate if you could guide me through what they actually meant:

> Suppose the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ has non-trivial solution. Show
>   that the linear system $Ax=b$ has either no solution or infinitely
>   many solutions.

**Answer:** If $Ax = b$ has a solution $x = u$, then $u + v$ is also a solution to $Ax = b$ for all solutions $x = v$ to $Ax = 0$. Hence $Ax = b$ has either no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

1. How does assuming $Ax = b$ having a solution $x = u$, leads to $u + v$ also a solution?
2. I don't understand this "for all solutions $x = v$ to $Ax = 0$".
3. How does it lead to the conclusion that $Ax = b$ has either no solutions or infinitely many solutions, when the explanation did not show the "no solution" aspect.

> Suppose the homogeneous linear system $Bx=0$ has infinitely many
>   solutions. How many solutions does the system $ABx=0$ have?

**Answer:** Let $x = u$ be any solution to the system $Bx = 0$. Then $ABu = A0 = 0$. The system $ABx = 0$ has at least as many solutions as the system $Bx =
0$. Thus it has infinitely many solutions.

1. What does this "The system $ABx = 0$ has at least as many solutions as the system $Bx =
   0$" mean?

Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend you go through [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) by 3Blue1Brown.

Comment: Is English your native language? If not, what is? [if you don't mind, that is]

Comment: @KennyLau I'm Korean, but i'm okay with English. Been using English for the past decade. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If $Ax=b$, then $A(u+v)=Au+Av=b+0=b$.
2. What I wrote above holds for every solution $v$ of the equation $Av=0$, not just to one or some of them.
3. If $Ax=b$ has a solution $u$, then, since the equation $Ax=0$ has, at least, one solution $v\neq0$, then every $\lambda v$ ($\lambda\in\mathbb R$) is also a solution of $Ax=0$, and therefore every $u+\lambda v$ is a solution of $Ax=b$.

---

1. If $u$ is a solution of $Bx=0$, then $(AB)u=A(Bu)=A0=0$. Therefore, every solution of $Bx=0$ is also a solution of $ABx=0$.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! A question: How does $(AB)u=A(Bu)=A0=0$  shows that every solution of $Bx=0$ is also a solution of $ABx=0$? Is it because of the fact that since $Bx=0$ has infinite solutions, the term $ABx$ being $= 0$ also implies the same?

Comment: @idolo If $u$ is such that $Bu=0$ (that is, if $u$ is a solution of $Bx=0$), then $(AB)u=A(Bu)=A0=0$ (that is, $u$ is a solution of $(AB)x=0$). This has nothing to to with the *number* of solutions.

Comment: How does every solution of $Bx=0$ is also a solution of $ABx=0$? Thanks.

Comment: @idolo I have already proved that twice, first in my answer and then in my previous comment. What is the passage that you don't understand?

Comment: I do not understand how does the above leads to the conclusion that every solution of $Bx=0$ is also a solution of $ABx=0$.

Comment: @idolo I started with “$u$ is a solution of $Bx=0$” and I ended with “$u$ is a solution of $(AB)x=0$”. Please tell me what is the step between these two points that you do not undertand.

Answer (score 1):

> If $Ax = b$ has a solution $x = u$, then $u + v$ is also a solution to $Ax = b$ for all solutions $x = v$ to $Ax = 0$.

This sentence may be a little bit difficult to understand. Allow me to rephrase it:

> If $Ax = b$ has a solution $x = u$, then let $x=v$ be a solution to $Ax = 0$: $x = u+v$ would also be a solution to $Ax = b$.

---

About your question 3:

1. $Ax = b$ either has no solution or has a solution.
2. If it has a solution, then it has infinitely many solutions.
3. Therefore, $Ax = b$ either has no solution or has infinitely many solutions.